# SAMD21 serial console cannot be used after sketch upload

Tags: arduino, samd21

I bought [this SAMD21 module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33012500524.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dn1Ozm6) and am having trouble with the serial console.
I have set up the IDE as follows:

- Board=Arduino M0
- Port=COM10 (Arduino Zero (Native USB port))
- Programmer=AVR ISP

Once I slowly double-press Reset on the SAMD21, I am able to upload code to it.
However, when the upload has finished, the board is reset, the code starts to run but the port disappears, so I am unable to see messages I send via Serial.print....

I understand that there is a protocol that puts the board in 'flash' mode and then resets it so it can run the uploaded code and that this is initiated when I double-press Reset and that this varies from board to board.

When using a Nano, Mega or ESP8266, the serial port is still there, after the upload has finished.

Is there something I am not doing (or doing wrongly) with the SAMD21?
If the serial port cannot be made to stay after the upload, is there a way that I can still display debug messages in some sort of console? (debug dongle?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the handling of USB is linked to your sketch. if your sketch crashes, USB is not handled. and the port can change after upload

Comment: Hi Juraj, I am testing with a sketch that just blinks the LED and does a Serial.print("Testing...");
The port simply disappears after the code is uploaded. 
It no longer shows under Tools/Port.